# Identification of an empty macro from pgfplots using \ifx

Tags: pgfplots, pgf-core

Consider following MWE and the output thereafter. I have defined an empty macro and used `\ifx` to identify it as such. However, when an empty macro is received from `\pgfkeysgetvalue`, `\ifx` doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}
\begin{filecontents}{test.dat}
  Time Distance
  0 0
  1 1
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableset{
  columns/Distance/.style={
     column name={$D_{\alpha}$},
  }
}
\begin{document}
%
\def\tmp{}
\ifx\tmp\empty
\noindent Tmp is \tmp.\\
\fi
%
\pgfplotstableread{test.dat}{\loadedtable}%
\pgfplotstableforeachcolumn\loadedtable\as\col{%
  \pgfplotstableset{columns/\col/.try}%
  \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/column name}\temp%
  \ifx\temp\empty%
    \noindent Temp is empty.\\%
  \else%
    \noindent Macro col is \col. Macro temp is \temp.\\%
  \fi%
}%
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of MWE]

I am not sure whether macro `\temp` returned by `\pgfkeysgetvalue` is `\empty`. But it doesn't print anything. I have looked at these related posts:

[How to check if a macro value is empty or will not create text with plain TeX conditionals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53068/how-to-check-if-a-macro-value-is-empty-or-will-not-create-text-with-plain-tex-co)

[Why doesn't \ifx work inside a node command in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43934/why-doesnt-ifx-work-inside-a-node-command-in-tikz)

[What is the difference between \pgfutil@empty and \empty in an \ifx environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43931/what-is-the-difference-between-pgfutilempty-and-empty-in-an-ifx-environment)

Comment: I've taken the liberty to reenter the links such that they are slightly more informative and also parsed automatically. Please revert back if you don't feel that it's proper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you modify your code to look like

```
  \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/column name}\temp%
\show\temp
  \ifx\temp\empty%
    \noindent Temp is empty.\\%
```

You will see `\temp` is `\relax` in the no value case, so test for

```
\ifx\temp\relax
```

Don't forget to take the `\show` out of the production code.

Comment: Wonderful! Did the trick.

Comment: It only does for the MWE... but that does not load `pgfplotstable` - in which case `/pgfplots/table/column name` is undefined (=`\relax`). If you load `pgfplotstable`, it has a different value.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger thanks for the clarification, I know nothing I just scattered some \show in the MWE:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sure - I would have done the some. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Your MWE is incomplete: it does not load `pgfplotstable`. However, `column name` is only available within `pgfplotstable`.

What beats me is that you did not get an error although you used an undefined key. Ah - it is the `/.try` handler. Apparently, it swallows the nested error message. I was unaware of that behavior ...

Anyway, I checked what happens if you load `pgfplotstable` (as you did for sure in your larger production code). And: `column name` is not empty initially. It only expands to an empty value (more precisely: to `\pgfkeysnovalue`). Apparently, this has some special support which is (alas) not documented:
- if you say `column name={}`, the column's display name is the empty string.
- if you say `column name=\pgfkeysnovalue`, the column's display name defaults to the column's name. This is the default.

I will adjust the documentation.

Here is a suitable solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}% ---------- CF
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}
\begin{filecontents}{test.dat}
  Time Distance
  0 0
  1 1
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableset{
  columns/Distance/.style={
     column name={$D_{\alpha}$},
  }
}

% --------- CF
\def\emptycolname{\pgfkeysnovalue}

\begin{document}
%
\def\tmp{}
\ifx\tmp\empty
\noindent Tmp is \tmp.\\
\fi
%
\pgfplotstableread{test.dat}{\loadedtable}%
\pgfplotstableforeachcolumn\loadedtable\as\col{%
  \begingroup% ---- CF
  \pgfplotstableset{columns/\col/.try}%
  \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/column name}\temp%
  \ifx\temp\emptycolname% ----- CF
    \noindent Temp is empty.\\%
  \else%
    \noindent Macro col is \col. Macro temp is \temp.\\%
  \fi%
  \endgroup% ---- CF
}%

\pgfplotstabletypeset\loadedtable
\end{document}
```

I introduced *four* changes: first, I loaded `pgfplotstable`. Second, I defined `\emptycolname` to contain the value that `pgfplotstable` assumes if you never assigned a column name: `\pgfkeysnovalue`. Third, a used that value in the `\ifx` comparison. Last (but not least), I introduced `\begingroup ... \endgroup` inside of your loop. Otherwise, you will inherit the `column name` of the previous loop iteration. I also added `\pgfplotstabletypeset` to see that it works.

See http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/TeX-programming-notes.pdf for how to transport local variables outside of a TeX group (if you need it).