# Wrapping environment passing optional argument to wrapped environment

Tags: beamer, environments, nesting

I'm trying to create a `myframe` environment which wraps a Beamer `frame` environment but sets a default title. Additionally, I want to be able to pass optional arguments to `myframe` which should then forward these arguments to `frame` (particularly, I need the `fragile` argument to work).

I thought the following would work, but it doesn't. How do I fix this code?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newenvironment{myframe}[1][]{
    \begin{frame}[#1]{Default Title}
}{
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myframe}
    Hello world
\end{myframe}

\begin{myframe}[fragile]
    \begin{verbatim}
        Hello world
    \end{verbatim}
\end{myframe}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm note sture you can wrap the fragile options. As far as I remember when the fragile env is in play the macros behind it looks explicitly for `\end{frame}` to do their thing, and when it is hidden like this it is never seen.

Comment: A start to fix things would be to provide feed back to answers you've gotten to your other questions.

Comment: Some commands process empty optional arguments differently than missing optional arguments (see \subfig).  These are difficult to emulated using \newcommand.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80180/identification-of-an-empty-macro-from-pgfplots-using-ifx for example.

Comment: Hiding `\end{frame}` behind a custom environment is an exceptionally bad idea - in many situations the code looks for the verbatim string `\end{frame}`.

Comment: Can you please clarify if all frames without title should have the default title or only some of them?